# Error while saving in jpeg format with using of imwrite

Tags: octave

I'm using Octave 3.6.4 with image-2.0.0 package installed. So, I got imfilter and other functions from this package working very well.

But when I try to do something like this:

```
imwrite(zeros([5 5 3],'uint8'),'1.jpeg')
```

I got error as follows:

```
error: imwrite: jpeg: unsupported or invalid image format
```

I'm using Lubuntu(think this is last stable one)
How can this be with jpeg? Also, imwrite currently working only with bmp as target format.

I was not able to find something in the web.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a very weird error. It works perfectly for me using Octave 3.6.4. 1) did you build Octave yourself or did you install it from the Lubuntu repositories? 2) do you have the `libgraphicsmagick++3` and `libgraphicsmagick++1-dev`packages installed? 3) Having the image package should not make a difference since imwrite is part of Octave core. 4) can you show us what appears when you run `gm version` on the command line (not at the Octave prompt)? My guess is that your GraphicsMagick was build without support for those file formats.

Comment: @carandraug
Ha... I've looked at "gm version" output and saw that there is no support for any kind of image formats. It seems like it was compiled without it. Thank you so much!

Comment: I have written instructions in how to build GraphicsMagick for Debian and debian based distributions (because the one distributed is limited to 8bit images). Read it [here](http://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned on the comments to the question, that's a very weird error, most likely a problem with the GraphicsMagick library. The command `gm -version` will show a table with all the formats that it was built to support. Here's my output:

```
Feature Support:
  Thread Safe              yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     yes
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 yes
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     yes
  JPEG-2000                yes
  JPEG                     yes
  Little CMS               yes
  Loadable Modules         no
  OpenMP                   yes (201107)
  PNG                      yes
  TIFF                     yes
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WMF                      yes
  X11                      yes
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes
```

If you're building Octave and GraphicsMagick from source, I recommend you take a look at the instructions I wrote to build [Octave](http://wiki.octave.org/Debian) and [GraphicsMagick](http://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick) in Debian (and debian based distros).